# Iterate over Python list potentially including other list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have some function that takes two arguments. I would like to iterate over a list of pairs of arguments, calling it on each pair:

```
arglist = [(arg1, 'Ni!'), (arg2, 'Peng!'), (arg3, 'Neee-Wom!')]
for arg in arglist:
    func(arg[0], arg[1])

# The pairs don't have to be tuples, just showing that way for convenience
```

Here's the twist - I would like to be able to have one argument of each pair sometimes be a list, in which case the overall iteration would go through each item in *that* list, calling the function on it and its partner. So this:

```
newwords = ['Ekke', 'ekke', 'Ptang', 'Zoo', 'Boing']
arglist = [(arg1, 'Ni!'), (arg2, 'Peng!'), (arg3, 'Neee-Wom!'), (arg4, newwords)]
for arg in arglist:
    func(arg[0], arg[1])
```

Should be equivalent to this:

```
arglist = [(arg1, 'Ni!'), (arg2, 'Peng!'), (arg3, 'Neee-Wom!'), (arg4, 'Ekke'), 
           (arg4, 'Ekke'), (arg4, 'Ptang'), (arg4, 'Zoo'), (arg4, 'Boing')]
for arg in arglist:
    func(arg[0], arg[1])
```

Is there a nice Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: "isinstance" allows to check if an object has a particular type (e. g. list). Then you can use an inner loop to iterate over the list items.

Answer (score 4):

Depending how frequent that list appears in pair.

If frequent - Go for try - except.

```
def try_except_method():
    for arg, item in args_list:
        try:
            for i in item:  # assuming item is following sequence protocol.
                do_something(arg, i)
        except TypeError:  # asking for forgiveness.
            do_something(arg, item)
```

This will run faster than testing condition in every iteration.

If not, checking condition with 'isinstance' just like other answers.

```
def is_instance_method():
    for arg, item in args_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for i in item:
                do_something(arg, i)
        else:
            do_something(arg, item)
```

For bonus, if you plan to use more types other than list and str -
Go for 'singledispatch'.

```
@singledispatch  # all types other than registers goes here.
def func(a, b):
    do_something(a, b)


@func.register(list)  # only list type goes here.
def func_list(a, b):
    for i in b:
        do_something(a, i)


def single_dispatched():
    for arg, item in args_list:
        func(arg, item)
```

Result of time took by each methods with your example.
Try playing with these with different data, here's [full code](https://pastebin.com/nVtX7iYH).

> 0.0021587999999999052
> 0.0009472000000001479
> 0.0024591000000000474

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for arg, value in arglist:
    if isinstance(value, list):
        for v in value:
            func(arg, v)
    else:
        func(arg, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

[isinstance()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp) is the one which will help you do that.

What you can do is, use `isinstance()` to check whether is it a list or not. And work on your possible function:

```
for arg in arglist:
  # if the item is a list go through each item and pass it with the arg[0]
  if isinstance(arg[1], type([])): 
      # passing arg[0] and item from array item of arg[0]
      for item in arg[1]: func(arg[0], item) 
  else: func(arg[0], arg[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def echo(x, y):
    print(x, y)

newwords = ['Ekke', 'ekke', 'Ptang', 'Zoo', 'Boing']
arglist = [('arg1', 'Ni!'), ('arg2', 'Peng!'),
           ('arg3', 'Neee-Wom!'), ('arg4', newwords)]
for arg0, arg1 in arglist:
    if isinstance(arg1, list):
        for item in arg1:
            echo(arg0, item)
    else:
        echo(arg0, arg1)
```

or

```
for arg0, arg1 in arglist:
    echo(arg0, arg1) if not isinstance(arg1, list) else [
        echo(arg0, item) for item in arg1]
```